# How to show/draw the spectrum frequency from line into bar shape (android)?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning how to make a spectrum analyzer. I learn from tutorial and here's the code

```
package com.example.prasetyo.spectrumanalyzer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import ca.uol.aig.fftpack.RealDoubleFFT;



/*public class SpectrumActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spectrum);
    }*/

public class SpectrumActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (started) {
            started = false;
            startStopButton.setText("Start");
            recordTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            started = true;
            startStopButton.setText("Stop");
            recordTask = new RecordAudio();
            recordTask.execute();
        }
    }

    int frequency = 8000;
    int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
    int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;


    private RealDoubleFFT transformer;
    int blockSize = 256;
    Button startStopButton;
    boolean started = false;

    RecordAudio recordTask;
    ImageView imageView;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Canvas canvas;
    Paint paint;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spectrum);

        startStopButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.StartStopButton);
        startStopButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        transformer = new RealDoubleFFT(blockSize);
        imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    /*public void onClick(View v) {
        if (started) {
            started = false;
            startStopButton.setText("Start");
            recordTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            started = true;
            startStopButton.setText("Stop");
            recordTask = new RecordAudio();
            recordTask.execute();
        }
    }*/


    private class RecordAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, double[], Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


            if(isCancelled()){
                return null;
            }

            //try {
                int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
                AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize);
                short[] buffer = new short[blockSize];
                double[] toTransform = new double[blockSize];

            try {
                audioRecord.startRecording();
            }
            catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                Log.e("Recording Failed", e.toString());
            }
                while (started) {
                    int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, blockSize);
                    for (int i = 0; i < blockSize && i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                        toTransform[i] = (double) buffer[i] / 32768.0; // signed 16 bit
                    }
                    transformer.ft(toTransform);
                    publishProgress(toTransform);
                    //Log.e("AudioRecord", "Recording Failed");
                    //return null;
                }
            return null;
        }


        protected void onProgressUpdate(double[]... toTransform) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            for (int i = 0; i < toTransform[0].length; i++) {
                int x;
                x = i;
                int downy = (int) (100 - (toTransform[0][i] * 10));
                int upy = 100;
                canvas.drawLine(x, downy, x, upy, paint);
                imageView.invalidate();
            }
        }

        /*public void onClick(View v) {
            if (started) {
                started = false;
                startStopButton.setText("Start");
                recordTask.cancel(true);
            } else {
                started = true;
                startStopButton.setText("Stop");
                recordTask = new RecordAudio();
                recordTask.execute();
            }
        }*/
    }
}
```

Spectrum will show up as line each frequency. If i'm not mistaken, the showed up line appear because of drawLine method. Is there any way to show the frequency in other shape (bar)? Really need help :)
Here's the illustration here is the ilustration https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3jsXXkRa7pLclFYMDdmUlk5MEU&authuser=0

Comment: You mean, cube like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oFzWhbHzO_Q

Comment: No, i mean like a bar. Like this http://www.google.co.id/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CAgQjRw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dsk.bielyvlk.spectrumanalyzer&ei=PIUuVYyxBoTKmAXujIHYCA&psig=AFQjCNEjNAcVuz5-bVKBt2n-bPjGwpgb-Q&ust=1429198524170443

Comment: I am sorry for my language :(

Comment: here is the ilustration https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3jsXXkRa7pLclFYMDdmUlk5MEU&authuser=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `canvas.drawLine(x, downy, x, upy, paint);` with `canvas.drawRect(x * 5, downy, x * 5 + 4, upy, paint);`

[Canvas.drawRect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRect%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29)

Comment: it works! Thanks dude :) Btw, is "+ 4" use to represent the width of each spectrum bar?

Comment: Yes, this will make each bar 4 pixels wide, so the bars will be separated. Change it to `+ 5` to remove gaps between bars.